# Reasons for someone removing my question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Someone is removing my questions. Is this correct procedure?

If the site is for students *and* professionals, then why is someone removing my questions?

Comment: Please post a link to one of these questions, or post a link to your user profile.

Comment: Never mind, I found you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734084/php-variable-value-changes-after-assignment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734084/php-variable-value-changes-after-assignment

Comment: this is the link when i asked the question a very large discussion on that topic it is very helpful to student, why someone is removing my questions..

Comment: it's my pleasure to being a part such a great community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Original Question:

## assigning a varible in php

When you assign a variable the value of 0123, it keeps coming up with a different number, why?

---

1. The word is "variable", not "varible", but that's not too bad.
2. Your question does not describe what your problem is. A couple of lines of code would have shown what you tried and would have shown what the problem is.

I would have voted to close this as "Not a real question". I would later have voted to delete this because it would never be of use to anyone else, since nobody else would have any idea which problem you were describing.

Comment: ok john i understand.

Comment: And: it did not mention *what* number it came up with (though many of us would know).

Comment: It also is an exact duplicate of this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412712/interview-question-in-php-is-123-0123

Answer (score 9):

No one person is deleting your questions, they were closed by the community, then deleted by community vote as well.

So your questions got 5 close as off-topic votes, then 3 votes to delete each.

Comment: what does it means for

Comment: @Rahul: one thing it means is that it is difficult to understand your questions. Maybe this is due to your English language skills, or maybe you just have difficulty expressing yourself in writing. I've seen several of your questions, and have voted to close or delete many of them. They're really very bad.

Comment: @Rahul: That means that the community not only thought that your question was off-topic, poorly formed, overly vague, or some other reason that it would be closed, but also that your question was bad enough that it shouldn't even show up on SO. As to why, I can't say, because I can't see deleted questions, but your questions must have been pretty bad to have been voted for deletion.

Comment: hi john saunders if this is my communication problem why i got large discussion on my topic.

Comment: @Rahul: because we're <strike>nice</strike> <strike>good</strike> ok people (mostly), and want to help. Notice that every single answer to this question was only guessing about what you were asking. If you had simply provided a few lines of code to demonstrate the problem, then you would have had _answers_, not _guesses_.

Comment: Careful with the word "community" in contexts like this, as it can be confused with the quasi-user "community".

Comment: @dmkee: littel 'c' little 'c' man

Answer (score 6):

Your question (*"[what does PHP mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733615/what-does-php-means-for)"*, which you asked *twice*) got closed and deleted because it is easily answered with a [Google search.](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=what+does+php+mean)

See http://de.php.net/manual/en/faq.general.php#faq.general.acronym.

which reads:

> PHP stands for PHP: Hypertext
>   Preprocessor. This confuses many
>   people because the first word of the
>   acronym is the acronym. This type of
>   acronym is called a recursive acronym.

Comment: @Rahul: I voted to close one of these as well. Did you really have no idea how to quickly find the answer to this question, using Google or wikipedia? If you really couldn't find the answer in five minutes, then I apologize for voting to close the question.

Comment: wish I could tell my granny that... "Seriously, granma? You couldn't plug the printer first before trying to print instead of making me drive all the way to fix it?"

Comment: @yoda: with all respect to your granny, if she don't know to plug stuff in before using it, then maybe it's time for child caps on all the electrical outlets.

Comment: @John: Child caps are only necessary if you plug everything in.

Comment: @yoda: I would just be concerned to learn what she thought should be stuck into the outlets. But enough of talking about the family members of people I don't know!

Comment: In my experience Grannies think that the *electric* leaks out if something is not plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been first closed from users who can vote to close questions. As far as I can see from the links reported by other users, the question has not been deleted.

Your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734084/php-variable-value-changes-after-assignment has been closed as duplicate; if it were not a duplicate, it could be closed because it doesn't shown any search effort.

> When you assign a variable the value of 0123, it keeps coming up with a different number, why?

One of the examples reported in [Integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) (the documentation page for PHP) explains how PHP interprets 0123.

```
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
```

If you are expecting a different value to be assigned to the variable, you are not correctly interpreting the code.